# How to use watch over selected options and add into an array in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

// i wanna put watch on option selection and put inside an array multipleVlaue bt its not working.

//Html

```
 <select  ng-model="category1" ng-options="item1 for  item1 in abms">
      <option value="" ng-init="category1"></option>
 </select>
```

//js

```
    $scope.multipleVlaue = [];
    $scope.$watch('category1', function(){
          $scope.multipleVlaue.push($scope.category1);
      }, true);
```

Here is the [Code](https://jsfiddle.net/ot7a2qvk/2/)
What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are the victim of not [Understanding the Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

In short, `ng-repeat` creates new child scope and primitive values like (Numbers, String, Boolean) when defined on parent scope doesn't update value from inside the child scope, so you need to use `.` dot in your `ng-model`

So your code would like this

```
// html
<select ng-model="obj.category1" ng-options="item1 for  item1 in abms">

//js
$scope.$watch('obj.category1', function (val) {
    if ($scope.obj.category1) {
        $scope.multipleVlaue.push($scope.obj.category1);
    }
    console.log($scope.multipleVlaue);
}, true);
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ot7a2qvk/3/)